# How to call a PartialView from outside the controller in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a common message box method that can be called throughout my `ASP.NET 5` application

The code should be something like this:

```
public class WebHelper
{
    public static IActionResult MessageBox(string message)
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_MessageBox.cshtml", message);
    }
}
```

And then in my controller call:

```
return WebHelper.MessageBox("Hallo world");
```

instead of what I am currently doing of :

```
 return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_MessageBox.cshtml", "Hallo world");
```

However  PartialView is bound to the controller so it seems I cannot use it outside the controller.

I tried to use [Answers 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642815/render-mvc-partialview-into-signalr-response) [Answers 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572619/render-partial-view-without-creating-an-actionresult) which are solutions for `ASP.NET 4` but they don't work in `ASP.NET 5` e.g.

```
 public string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        this.ViewData.Model = model;
        try
        {
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

as I can't find the  `ViewEngines.Engine`  in the `ASP.NET 5` namespaces.

Question:
What is the simplest way to solve my problem in `ASP.NET 5? Providing the method and calling method code

Comment: There's a sample around rendering views to strings here - https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString

Answer (score 3):

Here's the helper class that renders the view: (as you can see, the `ViewEngines.Engine` part that you couldn't find anymore is now injected as `IRazorViewEngine`)

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Internal;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Routing;

namespace WebApp.Demo.Helpers
{
    public class RazorViewToStringRenderer
    {
        private IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;
        private ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
        private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public RazorViewToStringRenderer(
            IRazorViewEngine viewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _viewEngine = viewEngine;
            _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public string RenderViewToString<TModel>(string name, TModel model)
        {
            var actionContext = GetActionContext();

            var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, name);

            if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Couldn't find view '{0}'", name));
            }

            var httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();

            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext = actionContext.HttpContext;

            var view = viewEngineResult.View;

            using (var output = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    view,
                    new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                        metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                        modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                    {
                        Model = model
                    },
                    new TempDataDictionary(
                        httpContextAccessor,
                        _tempDataProvider),
                    output,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions());

                view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                return output.ToString();
            }
        }

        private ActionContext GetActionContext()
        {
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            httpContext.RequestServices = _serviceProvider;
            return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
        }
    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       // Add MVC services to the services container.
       services.AddMvc();
       // Add the helper rendering class as singleton
       services.AddSingleton<RazorViewToStringRenderer>();
}
```

Get injected helper class in controller for example:

```cs
public HomeController(RazorViewToStringRenderer renderer)
{
       string message = "Hallo world";

       var partialView = renderer.RenderViewToString("~/Views/Shared/_MessageBox.cshtml", message);
}
```

Code from here, with a few tweaks to work with the old packages like `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"`: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString

If you're using the new `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-*"`, just get the code from there

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I came across the same issue and the links in the previous answers and comments now seem to be broken.

A solution that I've used to get around this is to create an abstract class which inherits from 'Controller'.

```
    public abstract class MyControllerBase : Controller
    {
        protected IActionResult MessageBox(string message)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_MessageBox.cshtml", message);
        }
    {
```

Just make sure that your controllers inherit from this base class and then in your controller you just need:

```
return MessageBox("Hello world");
```